# Attempted relative import in non-package after install script with setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I have this directory structure

```
parent/
   child/
      __init__.py
      sibling1.py
      sibling2.py

   setup.py
```

and this in my `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='parent',
      version='0.1',
      packages=['child'],
      scripts = ['child/sibling1.py'],
     )
```

and in `sibling1.py` i have `from . import sibling2`.

but when i run `sibling1.py` in the console i get 
`Attempted relative import in non-package`

I also tried with `from child import sibling2` but it does not work.

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

i fixed it adding `entry_points = {'console_script' : ['sibling1 = child:main']}` to `setup()` in `setup.py`
so i had to write a method called `main` in my `child/__init__.py` and there, i did the `from . import sibling2` now i run `sibling1` in console, and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to say `from <dir> import <file>`.  As long as all the folders are in your python path, you can just say `import sibling2`.   The from / import syntax is for importing specific elements from the file/class into the current namespace...it is not necessary for referring to parent directories.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when i just `import sibling2` i get `ImportError: No module named sibling2`

Comment: if you are working in Linux, you will need to set your PYTHONPATH environment variable to contain all the python subdirectories you want to work with.  In this case, something like `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:parent: parent/child` with whatever the real, full pathnames are.

Comment: sorry, should be colons, not semi-colons as the path separators

Comment: i keep getting the same exception.